# Android setPreviewSize, how to detect if 320x480 and 480x320 are both support?

Tags: android, camera

As title explains, I'm using setPreviewSize to set the Camera Parameters. but the Android documents said:

> For example, suppose the camera supports both 480x320 and 320x480 preview sizes.

so, I want use **getSupportedPreviewSizes** to detect if the camera support both preview size. the result is only 480x320, but 320x480 is also supported (I tested on more than one phone). I think there should be some function or field which can be used to detect the result, I search google, but not found.

Any one know the answer? Please help me. Thank you.

**Added**
My Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

and the result of getSupportedPreviewSizes:

```
320x240, 352x288, 480x320, 640x480, 720x480 ...
```

Comment: I think you need getSupportedPreviewFormats();

Comment: @MosheRabaev Sorry, I cant understand how can find the result from the image format?

Comment: Maybe the issue might be a certain permission in the Manifest file otherwise I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output PreviewSizes with a `StreamConfigurationMap` to get the sizes supported for your camera surface:

```
StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(
            CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

    Size previewSizes = new Size[];
    Size videoSizes = new Size[];

    previewSizes = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class);
    videoSizes = map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class);
```

Comment: Sorry, it's just a new api, but result is the same as the old api. I just tested it. And phone is Meizu Mx 5.